# Just want to search for "string".html files with the specified "string" from search bar - PHP

Tags: php, html, string, file, search

Im very new to PHP. Please help :)

I simply want the string entered from a search bar to pull up a .html file with the string in the filename.

Basically each .html page I have shows a list of books, where each .html page is by author (i.e. freud.html). So, when I search for "freud" books through the search bar, I want freud.html to show up.

I am not sure how to point the search bar string to the php file. Also, I am not sure how my searched string can pull up my desired .html file or simply an error page.

Here is my search bar:

```
<div class="search-container">
 <form action="searching.php">
   <input type="text" placeholder="Search Author..." name="search">
     <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
 </form>
</div>
```

Here is my PHP page that I found online:

```
<?php
// string to search in a filename.
$searchString = 'myFile';

// all files in my/dir with the extension 
// .html 
$files = glob('/*.html');

// array populated with files found 
// containing the search string.
$filesFound = array();

// iterate through the files and determine 
// if the filename contains the search string.
foreach($files as $file) {
$name = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_FILENAME);

// determines if the search string is in the filename.
if(strpos(strtolower($name), strtolower($searchString))) {
$filesFound[] = $file;
} 
}

// output the results.
print_r($filesFound);
?>
```

Comment: `glob('/*.html');` refers to the webservers filesystem root, not a subdirectory of your document root.

Comment: are all web servers filesystem roots similar? im using cpanel

Comment: My Opinion is having separate .html pages for each topic will eventually cause a maintenance nightmare.  For example what if you want to redesign the look of the site, now you have thousands of pages to change?  That's no good, it's fundamentally flawed.

Comment: how would you go about searching books from different pages?

Comment: If I was doing a project like that, I would write a web scrapper to go through the site, suck up all that stuff, put it in a database and then create 1 page that took a query paramenter like `somesite.com/books/?author=freud`  Then you just make a form with the action of GET, and you are all set.  No fuss, no muss.  Another note, is this allows you 0 flexibility in the search.

Comment: This is what a database is used for! Put all the book contents in a database, then when you perform a search, you find the contents book by querying the DB, load your HTML template, and put the book contents inside.

Comment: any links or tutorials that would get me started on that? very new here. thanks for the input guys! :)

Comment: I'd say a search engine / indexing system (eg Elastic) would be more performant than a typical relational database

Answer (score 1):

When the form:

```
 <form action="searching.php">
   <input type="text" placeholder="Search Author..." name="search">
     <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
 </form>
```

is submit, a GET request gets send to your webserver with the path `/searching.php`, and the GET parameter `search`=Your search input. Your webserver then loads your PHP file `searching.php` and executes it.

In PHP, you can access GET parameters with the [$_GET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) global array.

So, in your PHP, you can access the search string with `$_GET["search"]`.

For your second question, once you find the HTML file, you can display it with [readfile](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php). If a file is not found, you can load a different file such as `error.html` instead.

Comment: The form's `method` is not set so it will default to `get`, not `post`.